# CSS grid layout is broke by hiding children

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Having CSS with dynamically displayable items how do I avoid layout breakages? Hiding button A shift Edit button to the left, while I'd expect it to stick to the right edge of the grid.

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div style="width: 250px; border: 1px solid #ccc; display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(3, min-content) auto min-content;">
    <button _style="display: none;">A</button>
    <button>B</button>
    <button>C</button>
    <div></div>
    <button style="margin: auto; padding: 5px;">Edit</button>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change for button `"Edit"` `margin: auto` property to `margin-left: auto`.

Result: https://jsbin.com/qazekayahu/1/edit?html,output

P.S. Why you using CSS Grid for one-dimensional layout? Flexbox is better solution.

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div style="width: 250px; border: 1px solid #ccc; display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(3, min-content) auto min-content;">
    <button style="display: none;">A</button>
    <button>B</button>
    <button>C</button>
    <div></div>
    <button style="margin-left: auto; padding: 5px;">Edit</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```